# Error following simple c++ DLL tutorial with mingw

Tags: c++, gcc, dll, mingw, dllimport

I was following "Building and Using DLLs" tutorial from https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/dll.html.
I've made mydll.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>

void hello()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World of DLL" << std::endl;
}
```

compiled and linked it:

```
g++ -c mydll.cpp
g++ -shared -o mydll.dll mydll.o
```

then tried to use hello() function in main.cpp:

```
int main ()
{
  hello ();
}
```

after linking with `g++ -o main main.cpp -L./ -l mydll` and got:

```
 error: 'hello' was not declared in this scope
 hello();
```

The tutorial states that everything should work just fine. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linking process is separate from the compilation process. You have provided the library which contains the compiled definition of `hello` used in the linking process.

But during the compilation process, which happens before linking, the libraries are not used in any way. In order for the compiler to know what `hello` is, you need to still declare that function.

This is usually done by putting a forward-declaration in a header file shared by `main.cpp` and `mydll.cpp`.

```
// mydll.h

#ifndef HEADER_GUARD_MYDLL_H
#define HEADER_GUARD_MYDLL_H

void hello();

#endif
```

Then `#include "mydll.h"` in both `main.cpp` and `mydll.cpp`.